# Xcode: Error al modificar el StoryBoard

Tags: swift, xcode

Al tratar de modificar cualquier elemento de un storyboard me marca un error y necesito reiniciar el Xcode

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error es que me marca todo con lineas de color azul y cuando modifico algo no lo refleja en el storyboard, esto sucede al modificar o eliminar algun elemento[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuál error? En qué versión de Xcode?

Comment: Podrías dar más detalles sobre que error te aparece? Al abrir el storyboard, al mover un elemento, etc ?

Comment: me marca todo con lineas de color azul y cuando modifico algo no lo refleja en el storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Para desactivar esas lineas azules, tienes que desmarcar a Editor > Canvas > Bounds Rectangles como en la captura que adjunto a continuación.
Después de hacer esto, podrás editar el storyboard sin problemas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]